# How does OSReadLittleInt16() translate to Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I want to translate my Obj-C code to Swift.

I got these 3 lines in Obj-C:

```
NSData* data = ...
unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char*) data.bytes;
int16_t delta = OSReadLittleInt16(opticalEncoderBytes, 0);
```

The first two lines translate to:

```
NSData data = ...
let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
```

The third line is not that easy as I don't know:

1. Does `int16_t` simply translate to `Int16`?
2. `OSReadLittleInt16` is not available in Swift. Do I need to import something?

`OSReadLittleInt16` is defined in `usr/include/libkern/OSByteOrder.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.bigEndian` and `.littleEndian`

```
let i :Int16 = 1
print("i: \(i)")
let le :Int16 = i.littleEndian
print("le: \(le)")
let be :Int16 = i.bigEndian
print("be: \(be)")
```

> i: 1
> le: 1
> be: 256

```
let data: NSData! = "12345678".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt16>(data.bytes)

let ui0 = bytes[0]
let ui1 = bytes[1]
print("ui0: \(String(ui0, radix:16))")
print("ui1: \(String(ui1, radix:16))")

let be0 = bytes[0].bigEndian
let be1 = bytes[1].bigEndian
print("be0: \(String(be0, radix:16))")
print("be1: \(String(be1, radix:16))")

let le0 = bytes[0].littleEndian
let le1 = bytes[1].littleEndian
print("le0: \(String(le0, radix:16))")
print("le1: \(String(le1, radix:16))")
```

> ui0: 3231
> ui1: 3433
>
> be0: 3132
> be1: 3334
>
> le0: 3231
> le1: 3433

Note that the default in iOS is little endian.

Comment: How does it apply to my specific case? I have all bytes defined as `unsigned char*`. This `unsigned int8` as I know. How do I now translate to little endian `Int16`?

Comment: `let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt16>(data.bytes)`

Comment: Ok, the trick is to treat data.bytes as a sequence of `Int16` instead of `UInt8`,  thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should be `let be0 = UInt16(bigEndian:bytes[0])` because it is a conversion *from* big endian *to* host byte order. Of course it does not make any difference. It's the same thing as `ntohs()` vs `htons()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach: `OSReadLittleInt16()` is a defined
as a macro in `<libkern/OSByteOrder.h>` as

```
#define OSReadLittleInt16(base, byteOffset) _OSReadInt16(base, byteOffset)
```

The macro is not imported into Swift, but the `_OSReadInt16()`
function is, so you can do

```
let delta = UInt16(littleEndian: _OSReadInt16(bytes, 0))
```

A possible advantage is that this works also on odd offsets, even if the architecture allows only *aligned* memory access.

Comment: Great, this is a literal translation to Swift. Thanks!